# Source Code Check Please - Macro Nutrient Calculator

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, calculator

Im quite new to Android Dev, and well Programming also, 
Im doing a Project for College by doing a Macro-Nutrient calculator which will give a user their Calorie needs for the day depending on their goal,

I have it almost finished (I will implement more features soon) Just want to get this basic feature done,

It all seems to work fine, but the textView named "displayValue" is not outputting the result,
Can someone please give me some advice?

ANDROID XML-LAYOUT

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bmr_logo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weightInput"
         android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/defaultText"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/maintButton"
         android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="265dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bulkButton"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="265dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="225dp"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
       android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
        android:text="Gain Weight" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cutButton"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="265dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/heightInput"
      android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/defaultText"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Weight:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayValue"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
        android:textSize="12pt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
        android:text="Maintain Weight" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Cut Weight" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ageInput"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/defaultText"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textHeight"
       android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Height:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAge"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Age:" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA CODE

```
package app.college.fitnessapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Macros extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText ageInput;
    EditText heightInput;
    EditText weightInput;

    Button cutButton;
    Button maintButton;
    Button bulkButton;

    TextView displayValue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.macro_layout);

     // Find elements from the layout and Define them
        ageInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageInput);
        heightInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.heightInput);
        weightInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightInput);

        cutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cutButton);
        maintButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.maintButton);
        bulkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bulkButton);

        displayValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayValue);

        //Set button listeners
        cutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        maintButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        bulkButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int ageNum = 0;
        int weightNum = 0;
        int heightNum = 0;
        int result = 0;
        int calculate = 0;
        int percentAdd = 0;

        // Test to see if fields are empty
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(ageInput.getText().toString())
            || TextUtils.isEmpty(heightInput.getText().toString())
            || TextUtils.isEmpty(weightInput.getText().toString())) {
          return;
        }

        // This is to read the Edit Text fields from the layout and fill the Variables with Numbers
        ageNum =  Integer.parseInt(ageInput.getText().toString());
        weightNum = Integer.parseInt(weightInput.getText().toString());
        heightNum = Integer.parseInt(heightInput.getText().toString());

        //Defines which button has been clicked and will calculate accordingly
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.cutButton:
              calculate = (10*weightNum) + (6*heightNum) - (5*ageNum) + 5;
            percentAdd =  (calculate*1);
            result = calculate + percentAdd;
          break;
        case R.id.maintButton:
        calculate = (10*weightNum) + (6*heightNum) - (5*ageNum) + 5;
        percentAdd =  (calculate*1);
        result = calculate + percentAdd;
          break;
        case R.id.bulkButton:
            calculate = (10*weightNum) + (6*heightNum) - (5*ageNum) + 5;
            percentAdd = (calculate*1);
            result = calculate + percentAdd;
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }

        //Displays the output
        displayValue.setText(String.valueOf(result));
      }
    }
```

I have a feeling it is the last line with the displayValue output,

*This Problem is Solved...
If i make my variables such as ageNum, weightNum etc into floats and parse the string into a Float i then get this error "The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (float)"
But if I define them as Ints and parse the strings to Int i then get no error messgage but no output,
I would prefer to output as a float though, just incase a user would enter their weight at 78.5 or something,*

**This is my only problem now,
Im not getting any outputs :( in the displayValue Textview**

Any suggestions please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> then get this error "The method setText(CharSequence) in the type
>   TextView is not applicable for the arguments (float)"

You have to use the `setText()` method that accepts an object which implements the `CharSequence` interface (i.e like the `String` class). You can use the static method [`String.valueOf(float value)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28float%29).

```
displayValue.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Comment: Ah jeez, I cant believe I didnt see that o.O been looking at the code all day, Though I just altered it, and im still not getting any output :(

Though, thank you for this help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `setText(...)` takes as an argument a `java.lang.CharSequence` (e.g. a `java.lang.String`). You are passing an `int`.

Check out the `String` class for converting literals like `int` to `String`.

Comment: Yeah I was pretty dumb there =X..
Thanks for that, i have not changed it correctly, But still the textView is not giving me an output :(

Any suggestions?
Once again, thanks for your help :)